# Setup the name of a VLAN interface in Debian 10

Tags: debian, vlan

On Debian 9 I could define a VLAN in /etc/network/interface and give it a name:

```
auto server0
iface server0 inet static
        pre-up /sbin/ip link add link enp3s0 name server0 type vlan id 40
```

Unfortunately with Debian 10 it does **not** work anymore... If I do that (calling ip link add...) a new interface will be created as VLAN with the given ID, but the name is *renameXX*.

I can rename the created interface with *ip link set ...*, but I can't predict how the interface will be named from system when created...

Can someone suggest me a solution for my problem? Since I have many VLANs on the server, naming them will help me managing the server...

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution...
The problem was the .link file in /etc/systemd/network/... I wrote:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=52:54:00:ad:b9:bc

[Link]
Name=mgmt0
```

This was the problem, since all new VLAN interfaces have the same MAC-address and systemd tries to rename them... :(
Unfortunately (see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14952), I couldn't check the Type of the interface, since "ether" will not recognised due to a bug.
I didn't wanted to write "Type=!vlan", since I may have problem if in the future I'll use other type (bridges, etc.).

I got a working solution with:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=52:54:00:ad:b9:bc
Path=pci*

[Link]
Name=mgmt0
```

So I match the MAC-address **and** only PCI interfaces. Of course, I'll have problem if I'll use eg USB adapter, but I don't have them and the interface with this MAC is a **PCI**...

Hoping the bug for "Type=ether" will be corrected...

Have a nice week
Luca

Comment: 6 months later this issue seems still open in Debian Buster...thanks for the PCI tip will try.